# Which is more preferable? Try to downgrade Ubuntu version of an EC2 server or create a new instance altogether?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a dilemma, I am trying to set up the Microsoft slqsrv drivers for PHP and a laravel project so that it can connect to an RDS service and do my migrations, however, the Microsoft page dictates that the supported versions for the Ubuntu Server are 18, 20 and 21. The following snippet is the exact commands for an Ubuntu server from [the official Microsoft page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 21.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

Trying to run the commands without the if statement installs "something" but it ends up with errors, moreover, the pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv extensions do show up in the extensions list of PHP, running the command "php -m" shows that they are indeed loaded, but if I try to run the migration it shows the alert that the OBDC driver is missing.

What makes me think this is not working is that my EC2 instance has the Ubuntu 22 version, which would make sense since the drivers are not supported at the moment and are not installed properly. The options I concluded are that either somehow downgrade my Ubuntu version from my EC2 server or create a new instance with a version that supports the sqlsrv drivers. I don't know if there's a third option for the installation to work properly in this version, but I assume the previous two are the more sensible.

My question is, is it possible or recommended to downgrade the Ubuntu version of the EC2 server? or should I create a new instance with a compatible version?

Answer (score 2):

One of the main benefits of the cloud is resource provisioning speed.

It takes seconds to create a new EC2 instance, it's much easier & quicker to just create a new instance with the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS AMIs available.